# how can I draw a plane in gnuplot, when it is parallel to one of the coordinate planes (oxz, oyz, oxy)

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

the question is how to draw a plane, when its equation is, for instance: y + 5 = 0 ? Sorry, but I failed to find the answer in Google, and `splot` draws something really not expected:

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What command did you enter exactly to get that output ?

Comment: @kebs, `splot y +5 = 0;` - this is the exact command

Comment: @user907860 That command gives you an error: gnuplot stops reading it after `=`

Comment: @Miguel, then it is `splot y + 5`, I just did not try it before reply, because I don't know how to return from parametric mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gnuplot plots by default z as a function of x and y. Obviously, this does not correspond to what you are trying to plot, which is y = -5 (you are asking gnuplot to plot z = y + 5). What you can do is use parametric mode. For 3D, you have the variables u and v, which perfectly define a surface. In this case, since you fix y = -5, the triplet x, y, z is given by u, -5, v. In gnuplot you do:

```
set parametric
splot u,-5,v
```

[image]